# ¿Por que cuando quiero hacer ping de una computadora a otra en packet tracer me dice que se han perdido?

Tags: redes

Estaba haciendo este subneteo de esta topologia de red y en teoria si no equivoco ya esta lista para pasarla a Packet tracer, pero cuando lo paso a no me hace ping con todas las maquinas que estan en dicha topologia y no se si me llegue haber equivocado a la hora de sacar la subred.

[image: Esa es mi procedimiento]

Y esta es mi topologia

[image: topologia]

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Has realizado los siguientes pasos luego de subnetear?

- Asignar las ips a pc
- Asignar las ip de red (gateway) a la interfaz correspondiente del router de la red
- Asignar las ip de puertos seriales entre cada router y encender los puertos
- Eligir un protocolo de enrutamiento(Estatico, dinamico:rip, ospf) para que pueda haber comunicación entre subredes

Comment: Si ya lo hice y verifique de nuevo que estuviera correcta la información q esta en el packet tracer, pero lo que no estoy seguro es en el procedimiento que hice para sacar las subredes, según yo lo hice bien

Comment: Puedes verificar tus calculos en la siguiente pagina, es una calculadora de vlsm:  http://www.vlsm-calc.net/

Comment: Pero veo que solo tiene capacida de hasta 999 subreds y lo que tengo en subredes son 1024 ahi que podria hacer?

Comment: Eso depende la mascara de red que posea la ip principal a subnetear. Depende de la mascara tambien sera la clase de la red

Comment: Y de acuerdo con la clase de res podrá alcanzar, por ejemplo, una red de clase A soporta 1024 hosts, pero una red e clase c no

Comment: Para indicar la mascara se debe poner la ip principal seguida de una pleca el numero de bits decimal de la mascara
Clase A -> 10.0.0.0/8
Clase B-> 10.0.0.0/16
Clase C-> 10.0.0.0/24

Comment: http://blogsdelagente.com/blogfiles/networking/57121_tablaIPmask.JPG